# Solution of a system of quadratic inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

Is it possible to check if a system of quadratic inequalities has a solution ? More precisely, we have $n$ inequalities of the form $q_k(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) > 0$ where $q_k : \mathbb{R}^n_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ for $k\in \{1,2,...,n\}$ is a quadratic form restricted to the positive reals.